# How to capture the full contents of a canvas?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to create a canvas with an image and then apply a filter to it and then get the image data from that. As I look at using the canvas it, it is apparent that when I apply the effect (outer glow), the content will extend beyond the size of the canvas.

How can I capture an image of the canvas to include all the canvas content and not more?

How can I capture an image of the contents of the canvas when the contents may be larger than the canvas or when the contents may extend past the boundaries of the canvas?

I assume this question has been answered but I have not found it.

Example code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// canvas.width = ?;
// canvas.height = ?;

var canvasImage = new Image();
canvasImage.onload = (event)=> {
   context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width?, height?);
   // add an effect that draws pixels outside of the canvas area
   canvas.filters = "dropShadow(0,0,25,0)";

   var blob = canvas.toBlob((blob)=> {
      // save to file or get image data
   });

};

canvasImage.src = canvasImageSource;
```

I do not always know the width and height ahead of time. Of image elements I know the width and height before effects are applied. Of text elements I don't know ahead of time.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50632567/how-do-i-get-the-full-canvas-content-even-the-hidden-ones-with-javascript) but this is getting the SVG string. It does not show how to get the total canvas contents ...unless it gets the contents automatically???

I found [another related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf) but it does not describe what to do when the contents are larger, or smaller than the bounds of the canvas.

MDN [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage) that the canvas creates a fixed size drawing surface:

> The  element creates a fixed-size drawing surface

In my case, I don't know the size or negative position after  effects are applied. I do know the size of the image before effects but not text or other elements.

An example use case. I add an image at 0x0 and I set the size of the canvas to the size of the image. Then I add flat drop shadow (so the shadow is on all sides of the image). The total image size is now larger and it is to the top and left. How do would I get the total image size with effects?

Shouldn't there be something like `window.getComputedStyle(canvas, "size")`?
Also, when using the console, I noticed there are methods, `canvas.getBoundingRect()` and other similar methods. Would these work?

Answer (score 2):

The content that is drawn outside of the canvas is not drawn at all, so the question is kinda moot.

To do something like this you'd have to handle yourself the size a drawing will take, before it's drawn. Your example isn't using a valid syntax, but if we assumed it was generating a drop-shadow with a 25px spread value and no offset, then you'd need to add 50px in every direction to your unfiltered drawing size.
But that soon becomes a nightmare, things like big strokes can become huge depending on the [`miterLimit` rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors#a_demo_of_the_miterlimit_property). Some SVG filters may just not be accessible, and are anyway always hard to parse. And we don't even talk about when you add clipping areas or compositing...

If you're feeling adventurous though, I did write a little something that handles most simple cases for my [`CanvasLayer` prototype](https://github.com/Kaiido/CanvasLayer/blob/master/source/getSize/getSize.mjs). Feel free to borrow from it if you need.

Comment: Nicely done! I didn't know how this question would be received but you understand the challenge of this problem entirely.

Comment: *"The content that is drawn outside of the canvas is not drawn at all, so the question is kinda moot."* Reading this gave me an idea (that might be what you're doing). That is, create a giant canvas, add the image or contents to the middle, add the effects and then get that image data. Then loop through the image data from top to bottom and find the first non transparent pixel. Do that for all edges. Although, now I'm not sure if canvas has support for transparency.

Comment: Related question: What do you call the box that includes only the content and what do you call the box that is the content including the effects? In your code you have a few descriptions `layerBox, clippedBox, bounding box`.

Comment: IIUC the CanvasLayer is attempting to solve issues of having separate areas of content? Having a way of defining `layers` solves that? This sounds like the `HTML DOM` or a `DisplayTree`. If that's the case then you might try to simply follow their API (addNode, removeNode, moveNode, etc). I think CanvasLayers are needed and API for it

Comment: So I would use CanvasLayer instead of Canvas and then call the getSize() method? Or the getImageData()? I can ask on the forums or a basic code example work. I read the note that `drop-shadow` filter isn't supported though? PS I've never added this many comments on a post before lol

Comment: No CanvasLayer is something else entirely that we're working on at WHATWG, it just so happens I had to write the `getSize()` method for it, so you can copy part of the code and adapt it to yours.

Comment: I had an invitation to whatwg or w3 working group. I can't remember but i lost it and also i was working a lot at the time. Is this something I can still join?